# Spring getResources() -> get path for each resource throws exception at getFile()

Tags: java, spring

I need to get a list of paths to files for a given pattern.

```
Resource[] resources = context.getResources("classpath*:**/i18n/**/*.properties"); 
...
File file = resources[i].getFile(); /// throws exception
String path = file.getPath();
```

This works when run from IntelliJ, but fails when run from jar file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jar:file:/home/mariusz/.../.../build/libs/app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar!/i18n/test.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/home/mariusz/../../build/libs/app-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar!/i18n/test.properties
```

It returns proper resource, but resource.getFile() throws exception.

How to get path from Resource in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

`File` is a file system file on disk. A (read-only) *resource* is on the class path, possibly packed in a jar/ear/war (zip archives).

The basic java access is via the class loader or class:

```
URL url = MyApp.class.getResource("..."); // When in a jar: "jar:file:..."
InputStream in = MyApp.class.getResourceAsStream("...");
```

So use an InputStream instead of a File.

With a Spring `Resource`:

```
Resource resource = ...;
InputStream in = resource.getURL().openStream();

Path path = Paths.get("/home/mariusz/test.properties");
Files.copy(in, path); // Copies the resource to a real file.
```

---

A Path inside a resource:

```
Path res = Paths.get(resource.getURI());
```

Comment: but how can I get path for: Path path = Paths.get("/home/mariusz/test.properties"); ? I need to get it somehow from Resource

Comment: A file zipped inside a jar? Added, though not used that one.

Comment: Path res = Paths.get(resource.getURI()); throws exception: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `getFile()` method which return a java.io.File.
java.io.File represents a file on a file system.
The Jar is a java.io.File. But anything within that file is beyond the reach of java.io.File, unless uncompressed.

Use `resource.getInputStream()` instead.

Comment: and then how can I get file path out from input stream?

Comment: You can't, InputStream can be defined as a sequence of data, it will just return to you the data read from the file inside your jar.

Comment: I saw your comment in @Joop Eggens answer, when you used the `Paths.get(URI uri)` it might be related to this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7161